# Foreign text in joomla articles

Tags: php, joomla

Randomly foreign text apperars in a few items .

I deleted the article added them again . But this is happening with one or the other article every-time.

Site url : http://bscglobaledu.org/new/
Built on : Joomla
Template : Gavickpro university
Issue pages : http://bscglobaledu.org/new/index.php/test-prep/gre

I would like to 
remove кредит на машину
шиферная крыша

Some one please help .

Comment: You probably downloaded to template from an illegal website buy it here https://www.gavick.com/joomla-templates/university,165.html and you will not have those link in your articles

Answer (score 0):

This is adware from stolen gk_university themplate . 
Try to search in code 'gk_fyuyu' and remove this block.
If you don't find try to search functions like base64_decode , eval , gzinflate .

Answer (score 0):

Go to
Html\com_content\Article\default.php     line 227

and

Html\Com_k2\templates\Default\item.php    line 126

remove the block below

base64_decode($gk_yuy)